# Free abelian groups in Algebraic Topolgogy

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the context of algebraic topology, free abelian groups are frequently used
like the parameter of functions $\textbf{X}$ in $f(\textbf{X})$

Since i am lack of knowledge about abstract algebra, i'd like to know what is free abelian group and how it is used in algebraic topology in some sense.

Comment: The free abelian group over a set $S$ is $\bigoplus_{S} ℤ$, sometimes written as $\bigoplus_{s ∈ S} ℤs$. It’s an abelian group in which $S$ is a $ℤ$-basis, that is you *can uniquely write* any element of the group as a linear combination of elements of $S$. Have you already had a look at what [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group) has to say about this?

Comment: I'm afraid it is going to be a very tough way through Algebraic Topology without a rather good basis in abstract algebra.    All the universities I know of demmand it as *pre-condition* for alg. topology. Are you studying on your own?

Comment: @Timbuc, I just took one semester courses of abstract algebra among three courses, and i almost forget many things about them. I am familar with topology in some undergraduate level, so far, Algebraic Topology class material does not seems to be difficult, anyway i'll try to cover the gaps from abstract algebra. Thanks four your comments

Comment: I will try to read Lang's algebra or fraleigh's algebra text to cover some undergraduate level of abstract algebra. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FreeAbelianGroup.html) - "A free Abelian group is a group $G$ with a subset which generates the group $G$ with the only relation being $ab=ba$."

"For instance, in algebraic topology, chains are formal sums of simplices, and the chain group is the free abelian group whose elements are chains." ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group)).